# Disable/remove “Switch to This Tab” suggestions in Chrome/Brave omnibar?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, tabs, address-bar, brave

It annoys me that when I type in the omnibar for Brave or Chrome, that among my suggested automatic completions are catfish results that upon selection change my tab.

Is there any way, such as by flags or extension, to prevent these appearing?